# Is there a way to see pricing based upon my resources?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

If I use the pricing calculator to select a VM instance running Windows, I can see an estimate for the month.

Once I deploy a VM, Azure has several resources associated with it, such as network adapters, security groups, etc.  All of those components, including the CPU's, drives, memory determines how much I am charged.

Is there a way to see the monthly cost of each "atomic" resource?  I might create a VM and then resize it to another instance size, or add a hard drive.

How can I "crawl" my resources and see what each element is costing me (and is going to cost for the month)?

Answer (score 0):

There a numerous ways on checking the cost of your billing:

If you click on your subscription on the [subscription blade](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Billing/SubscriptionsBlade) it would give you some information on how much you are using, and an estimation on when you would burn though your credits.

[image: sub blade]

There are better tools out there which will require to make a VM (e.g. Hanu). Currently the Azure billing portal is available on [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureUsageAndBillingPortal) which will soon be implemented in azure.